# provide Select statement in procedure parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

Hi i'm working on this query in oracle and i need to provide many id to a procedure from a table. how can i  provide each id from a table to my procedure. sory i'm kinda new at this im completely lost i dont know what to search.
here's

Procedure

```
 PROCEDURE procedname(in_id in VARCHAR2)

select id from mytable
```

Here's what i tryed

```
 execute procedname(select id from mytable);
```

but did no work

Is there a way to achive this?
Hope somone help me out with this

Comment: Does the procedure take one ID at a time or a list of IDs?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a collection of numbers. Here is an example on how to pass.

```
--sys.odcinumberlist is a collection which can hold numbers..

create procedure sp_test(i_id in sys.odcinumberlist)
as
l_cnt int;
begin
 select count(*)
   into l_cnt
   from TABLE(i_id); /* the TABLE keyword is used to unfold the collection of numbers as rows..*/
   dbms_output.put_line(l_cnt);
end;
/
```

--calling the stored procedure

```
begin
  dbms_output.enable;
  sp_test(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3,4,5,6)); /* here i am passing a list of numbers from 1 to 6*/
  --the procedure will count the number of elements in the input collection which is 6 
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use a SQL statement as an argument for a procedure or function. Since that needs an `INTO` clause in order to return the content of the SELECT statement. Your case suggests a CURSOR as needs to return all the records at a time. For this, a possible sample solution using `SYS_REFCURSOR` as an `IN/OUT`(or just `OUT`) type of parameter would be ;

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE mytable( id VARCHAR2(1) );
SQL> INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('A');
SQL> INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('B');

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Convert_ID(p_myrecordset IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 
BEGIN 
  OPEN p_myrecordset FOR
    SELECT id, ASCII( id )
      FROM mytable
     ORDER BY id;    
END;
/

SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SQL> DECLARE
  l_cursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  l_value1  mytable.id%TYPE;
  l_value2  INT;
BEGIN

  Convert_ID(p_myrecordset => l_cursor);            
            
  LOOP 
    FETCH l_cursor
    INTO  l_value1, l_value2;
    EXIT WHEN l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_value1 || ' - ' || l_value2 );
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE l_cursor;
END;
/

A - 65
B - 66
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=da51461f38124ce6c77a197db99008b7)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

To take each `id` from `some table` and call `sometable(id)`, a PL/SQL loop would be something like this:

```
begin
    for r in (
        select id from sometable
    )
    loop
        procedname(r.id);
    end loop;
end;
```